# Symmetricds Looping Configuration

Tags: symmetricds

Using SymmtricDS 3.9:-

I have corp database which with replicate store-1 database in bi-direction. 
But as per log configuration are looping again and again from corp to store and store to corp. 
Below are getting printed in corp log :-

```
[corp-1] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[corp-1] - RouterService - Routed 5 data events in 49 ms
[corp-1] - PullUriHandler - 5 data and 3 batches sent during pull request from store:2:2
[corp-1] - DataLoaderService - 5 data and 3 batches loaded during push request from store:2:2.
[corp-1] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[corp-1] - RouterService - Routed 5 data events in 187 ms
[corp-1] - PullUriHandler - 5 data and 3 batches sent during pull request from store:2:2
[corp-1] - DataLoaderService - 3 data and 2 batches loaded during push request from store:2:2.
[corp-1] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[corp-1] - RouterService - Routed 3 data events in 94 ms
[corp-1] - PullUriHandler - 3 data and 2 batches sent during pull request from store:2:2
[corp-1] - DataLoaderService - 4 data and 3 batches loaded during push request from store:2:2.
[corp-1] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[corp-1] - RouterService - Routed 4 data events in 111 ms
[corp-1] - PullUriHandler - 4 data and 3 batches sent during pull request from store:2:2
[corp-1] - DataLoaderService - 4 data and 3 batches loaded during push request from store:2:2.
[corp-1] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[corp-1] - RouterService - Routed 4 data events in 94 ms
[corp-1] - PullUriHandler - 4 data and 3 batches sent during pull request from store:2:2
[corp-1] - DataLoaderService - 4 data and 3 batches loaded during push request from store:2:2.
[corp-1] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[corp-1] - RouterService - Routed 4 data events in 59 ms
[corp-1] - PullUriHandler - 4 data and 3 batches sent during pull request from store:2:2
[corp-1] - DataLoaderService - 4 data and 3 batches loaded during push request from store:2:2.
```

below is getting printed in store log:-

```
[store-2] - PushService - Pushed data to node corp:1:1. 4 data and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:1:1 on queue default. 4 rows and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[store-2] - RouterService - Routed 8 data events in 63 ms
[store-2] - PushService - Push data sent to corp:1:1
[store-2] - PushService - Pushed data to node corp:1:1. 4 data and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:1:1 on queue default. 4 rows and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[store-2] - RouterService - Routed 8 data events in 115 ms
[store-2] - PushService - Push data sent to corp:1:1
[store-2] - PushService - Pushed data to node corp:1:1. 4 data and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:1:1 on queue default. 4 rows and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[store-2] - RouterService - Routed 8 data events in 120 ms
[store-2] - PushService - Push data sent to corp:1:1
[store-2] - PushService - Pushed data to node corp:1:1. 4 data and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:1:1 on queue default. 4 rows and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[store-2] - RouterService - Routed 8 data events in 122 ms
[store-2] - PushService - Push data sent to corp:1:1
[store-2] - PushService - Pushed data to node corp:1:1. 4 data and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - PullService - Pull data received from corp:1:1 on queue default. 4 rows and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
[store-2] - ConfigurationChangedDataRouter - About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
[store-2] - RouterService - Routed 8 data events in 64 ms
[store-2] - PushService - Push data sent to corp:1:1
[store-2] - PushService - Pushed data to node corp:1:1. 4 data and 3 batches were processed. (sym_node, sym_node_host, accounttypes)
```

> About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came
>   through the data router

above printing again and again. i tried drop database and reconfigure it again but same issue.

**EDIT**

I have used same configuration with SymmtricDS 3.7 and its working fine without any issue with looping.

not sure what is causing issue between 3.7 and 3.9 version.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try deleting from sym_node_identity at the store to see if it will request configuration and get you out of the loop.